# Linear Algebra Subspace Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Is the set of all polynomials of degree at most 3 with integer coefficients a subspace of Pn (for n >= 3)?

Im thinking no, for the set in question has polynomials with degree 3 and below while Pn seems to contain 3 and above, at least that is how I interpreted the question. I appreciate it!

Comment: The question is asking if it is a **subspace of**, not necessarily the entire space.  Checking if something is a subspace is an incredibly common first exercise in studying vector spaces and linear algebra.  Do you know what the definition of a subspace is?  What properties do you need to check whether or not your set has?  Does your set satisfy all of these properties?  Why?  (*Hint: it should in a lot of regards but fails one small thing*)

Comment: As an aside, the very top result on the Related tab on the right yields [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26249/which-of-the-following-polynomials-are-subspaces-of-mathbbp-n-for-an-approp?rq=1) which happens to contain this question inside of it, except the person who asked *that* question actually put some effort into his post.

Answer (score 0):

It is not stable by scalar multiplication.